# One way high ping when directly connecting two devices

Tags: ping, cable

i have just made crossover cable, and connected my desktop computer with laptop to test it, but i am experiencing high ping on laptop > desktop

desktop 10.10.10.1, laptop 10.10.10.2

**pinging laptop from desktop**

```
Reply from 10.10.10.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

**pinging desktop from laptop**

```
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=313ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=111ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=311ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=109ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=308ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=106ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=304ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=103ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=150ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=215ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=100ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=299ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=88ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=90ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=289ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes=32 time=488ms TTL=128

(not related to above)
Ping statistics for 10.10.10.1: 
Packets: Sent = 34, Received = 34, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 480ms, Average = 124ms
```

**desktop is not under heavy load, i also connected desktop to router(as its usually connected) and pinged it with router software, and it responded with perfect 1ms**

any ides what could be causing this ?

EDIT
direct connection with straight cable - same results

Comment: My first guess is the cable.

Comment: You made your own cable?  Why?

Comment: Try without a crossover, also, because most (or all) modern NICs are MDI-X capable, eliminating the need for a crossover cable.

Comment: @Tom O'Connor, same results with straight cable, d>l 1ms, l>d 1-1000ms

Comment: Nice. Hopefully someone here will be able to help you.  Out of my hands now ;)

Comment: Can you post the ping statistics of the ping command?

Comment: @user555 Ping statistics for 10.10.10.1:
    Packets: Sent = 34, Received = 34, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 480ms, Average = 124ms

Comment: Are both machines negotiating to the same link speed and duplex?

Comment: Could you try this again with IPv6 disabled on both laptop and desktop and see if results change?

Comment: @CMcKeown both have 'auto negotiation', i am on windows, and i dont have anything to check duplex, but connection speed is 1Gbps, that makes it full duplex i think, can test manual duplex settings if necessary

Comment: @DLMono ipv6 was disabled from the beginning

Comment: i have edited title etc. a bit since its not only about crossover anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have disabled everything(QoS, MS file sharing etc.) except ipv4 in connection properties on both machines, and reinstalled ethernet drivers for my laptop, rebooted laptop and then first ping was like:

```
<1ms
<1ms
400ms
<1ms
```

then it starts responding with stable <1ms, and file transfer speeds went up 2-3 times, 
not sure if its permanent fix, or just somethings caprice, but for now ping is good, both ways